# Providing phantom power to 3.5mm mic

Tags: mixing

I need to provide power to a mic that has 3.5mm jack. All of the external phantom power supplies are for XLR. Does anyone know of a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be extremely surprised if your mic needed phantom power with only a mini jack. Phantom power is 48V and it would likely fry your mic.

See this thread for some more details about what power you might need;

http://www.dvinfo.net/forum/all-things-audio/514394-xlr-mini-jack-adapter-phantom-power.html

Comment: Phantom Power is completely different than plug-in power! New lesson learned. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Usually mics that need phantom power come with an XLR plug, as phantom power does not usually get fed through jack plugs/sockets. Especially 3.5mm jacks. Having said that, some of my minidisc recorders provide some sort of power to some mics, but I doubt it's the sort of phantom power(48v) that's available on mixers, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use a USB power injector, like this:  [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00I6ILPPC/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I6ILPPC)

Comment: Matt - if you read Jamie's question and the comment underneath it, you'll see the OP was mistaken!