# jack 3.5mm condenser microphone (SubZero intrument) requiring phantom power, but working better without?

Tags: mixing

This question has been posted here with no answer, except that "you should probably not use phantom on a mini jack microphone" : [Providing phantom power to 3.5mm mic](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38316/providing-phantom-power-to-3-5mm-mic?newreg=5ba2353f21474e9e939d2d1ef4d67e04)

...However, I've got the Subzero clip on condenser intrument microphone, and the description says it does require phantom !
https://www.gear4music.fr/en/PA-DJ-and-Lighting/SubZero-Instrument-Condenser-Microphone/1OGY

By the way, I can't find any documentation/specification for this mic except this commercial website...

I tried the VXLR adaptor to power it with my MG16XU console. But when I enable the phantom power, I have a highly noisy input while with no phantom, the sound level seems okay... any tips ?

Comment: I have one of those microphones, and it works well with Gear4Music's own SubZero XLR adaptor.

Comment: Which I think is also a DC-DC converter (like the VXLR +) that itself requires phantom, but not the mic. Could you measure the tension between the contacts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vendor description is wrong. The microphone does actually require plugin power supply which is not phantom.

I hope they will correct it soon, because it is really misleading.

The microphone works very well with the VXLR pro or +

Answer (score 1):

Not all VXLR adaptors support phantom power.

For example, [here](https://rode.com/en/accessories/adaptors-cables/vxlr) is a 3.5mm mini jack to XLR VXLR adaptor that warns, "It is not compatible with microphones that require plug-in power, such as the VideoMicro". In this case, that's because it's a mono adaptor. You only need a mono mic signal, but you need the phantom power to be passed through on the third connector.

Using a VXLR adaptor that doesn't support phantom power would either just not work, or could possibly cause the symptoms you describe by partially shorting the connectors.

Try to get hold of a VXLR adaptor that definitively does support phantom power.

Comment: it's said that it does not support "plug in power" which is ~2.5V (the one that is mentioned in the thread linked in the question). The Rode VXLR is a simple adapter with the 3 XLR contacts forwarded to the jack TRS. This mention is to differentiate it from the VXLR+, which also acts as a Phantom-Plugin DC-DC converter.

Comment: However, on the mic's description from the vendor website, it's is said it needs "Phantom (48V)" power supply, which is the true phantom...

Comment: The "not compatible" message may be referring to the fact that TRS will short across the wrong contacts as the cable in inserted.

Comment: @hl037_ I'm still not clear which VXLR you're actually using? Anyway, sounds like you're on the case with following that possibility through. Let us know if you do get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I would have added "Pro" or "+" if it was the DC-DC converter version. The one I used was the simple one with just the contacts forwarded, since the vendor pretended it required phantom (on the microphone sold alone page, without adapter). As I said as answer, with a DC-DC conversion, it work.